# Laravel 5.5, Get next/previous Eloquent model, in order of alphabetically sorted ‘slugs’

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, sorting, eloquent

I have an Eloquent model with an alphanumeric `slug` field (which is not the primary key).

I’m implementing `getNextAttribute()` and `getPreviousAttribute()` custom getters, the purpose of which is to:

- eagerly pre-load the record’s “neighbors” in the list of records sorted alphabetically by `slug`;
- pre-load `null` if the current record is in terminal position.

(Think of it as a table of dictionary entries. They are sorted by term, and it’s logical to pre-load next and previous entry.)

How does one optimally attack such a problem? Maybe I come at it wrong already?

---

Not making myself clear.

Given we have a `records` table:

```
id      slug
--      ----
1       Tango
2       Alpha
3       Zulu
4       Bravo
5       Zulu
6       Foxtrot
```

When we go:

```
$record = App\Record::where('id', 5)->get();
```

Then we should get:

```
$this->assertEquals(null, $record->next);
$this->assertEquals(3, $record->previous->id);
```

Comment: may be you should describe elaborately with what you have done so far, i mean with code

Comment: Must have worded it badly, I haven’t written anything working yet. Feel like it should be easy, but somehow hitting the wall.

Comment: Isn't this just a simple database query? I presume you're ignoring locales and case sensitivity. How would you have done it if you had id=50 and wanted id 49 or 51? Could you do this with some ordering and only taking the first matching entries?

Comment: Atleast tell us clearly what do you really want, may be you could describe it using your DB table and column, what do mean by `record’s “neighbors”` etc

Comment: Edited to clear up my question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but with a numerical sort.  In the end I pulled a collection of all models and then used the first and last functions to get the next and previous.

Extrapolating to your case in your records model:

```
protected function siblings(){
    return Records::all()->sortBy('slug')
}

public function next(){
    $next = $this->siblings()->first(function ($value, $key) {
            return $value->slug > $this->slug;
        });
return $next;
}

public function previous(){
    $previous = $this->siblings()->last(function ($value, $key) {
        return $value->sort < $this->sort;
    });
return $previous
}
```

This automatically returns null if the record is the first or last in a set.